# What unifies modern geometry?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

As a teenager, I found my way to Euclid's Elements which opened the door to Euclidean geometry. Later in high school, I enjoyed contests and olympiads, but was puzzled by the occasional pop-up of projective geometry and inversive geometry, where I was able to use some of their techniques from time to time but I did not understand what these spaces really meant or how they were constructed. Once I got to second and third year of university, things started getting stranger. There were manifolds and calculus on manifolds, differential forms, and curvature, and I didn't know why they were studied (in retrospect, taking physics courses might have helped). I started hearing about hyperbolic geometry and other "geometries" whatever that means. One professor mentioned algebraic geometry and even "arithmetic geometry".

Questions:

1. What are the underlying concepts that unify these areas and make them all a part of the study of geometry?
2. Is there a definition of "geometries" like Euclidean/spherical/hyperbolic/elliptic geometry?
3. What, if any, generic goal or program is there for geometry? I'm guessing that determining the shape of the universe is an important question, but I don't know if there are more central ones.

Comment: You can try with F.Borceux, [Geomteric Trilogy (Springer)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319018041)

Comment: But still valuable the one-hundred years old Felix Klein [Elementary Mathematics from an Advanced Standpoint : Geometry (1924-28) (Dover, 2004)](https://books.google.it/books?id=JazDAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA both books look like excellent resources and I was not aware of either. Thank you very much for mentioning them.

Comment: You are welcome. In a nutshell: "What unifies geometries ?" A "general" concept of *space*. "What unifies modern geometry?" The use of "algebraic" methods.